# How to make a package-supporting java compiler?

Tags: java, batch-file, package, notepad++

Is there any way to create a java compiler/program runner in Batch that can automatically compile Java source files that are part of packages? I have been all over stack overflow for this, and have found absolutely nothing. I am currently using Notepad++. Please note that I am doing this just to gain a better understanding of the java build process.

Right now, I have this basic compiler/runner set up :

```
javac -d ..\..\bin $(FILE_NAME)
java -classpath ..\..\bin $(NAME_PART)
```

Do note that I am using Notepad++-specific variables, like `$(FILE_NAME)` and `$(NAME_PART)`. You get the basic idea though. I do know how to run packaged classes from the command line (java .), but I have no clue as to how to automate it. I would like it to output this result:

```
javac javac -d ..\..\bin $(FILE_NAME)
java -classpath ..\..\bin [packagenamevariable].$(NAME_PART)
```

Thanks for considering this question!

Comment: If you want to restrict your compilation and running to a package (I guess the package is part of a larger project), you could use an Ant script. If it is the whole project I would suggest setting it up with Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I find it much simpler then `ant`

A very minimal `gradle` setup looks like:

```
.
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── foo
                    └── bar
                        └── Main.java
```

where `build.gradle` contains

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "com.foo.bar.Main"
```

and `Main.java`

```
package com.foo.bar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

With `gradle` installed you can simply call `gradle run` and the following happens:

```
$ gradle run
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run
Hello world

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.836 secs
```

there are other tasks besides `run`. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

One useful task is `installDist` that creates a .bat file to start just the code in `./build/install/{projectname}/bin/{projectname}.bat`. That way you can start the code without all the gradle noise.

It's also possible to use gradle without installing it on your system by using gradle wrapper: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

- replace `gradle` in above commands with `gradlew.bat`
- the easiest solution to get the required files (`gradlew.bat` and the files in `/gradle/wrapper`) is to steal them from some project that has them. Picked randomly from github: https://github.com/quinnliu/sampleGradleProject

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I've been looking at Gradle tutorials for a while now, but I've been a bit confused as to what Gradle does. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> I have been all over stack overflow for this, and have found absolutely nothing.

That's because this is really hard to write a general purpose Java compile/run framework using just BAT scripts.

And unnecessary.

> I am currently using Notepad++, and do NOT wish to change to IDE currently.

That's fine.  You don't have to use an IDE.

Instead, you can install a Java-aware build tool such as Ant, Maven or Gradle.

(For a small project with minimal library dependencies, Ant will work nicely.  For larger projects, Maven or Gradle would be better.)

Comment: Much appreciated. I have looked in to Ant a little bit, but I never really understood how it was related to compiling. Also, I couldn't find a way to automate the creating of the xml files. Thank you though; I will probably ask another question about Ant at some point.

Comment: If you want to create the "build.xml" file automatically, use an IDE :-).